# How do I include GitHub secrets in a python script?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to move my bot written using discord.py/pycord to github for easier access, and I accidentally pushed my bot tokn to the hub, thankfully discord reset it for me and nothing hapened.

Now i want to use GitHub repository secrets to prevent this from happening, but i am having some trouble when trying to import the token into my code.

Here I've made a simple repo to experiment with this:

test.py:

```
import os
SECRET = os.environ['SECRET']
if SECRET == "TrustNo1":
    print("No one can be trusted")
print(SECRET)
```

workflow.yml:

```
name: build bot.py
on: [push]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: load content
              uses: actions/checkout@v2
              
            - name: load python
              uses: actions/setup-python@v4
              with:
                python-version: '3.10' # install the python version needed

            - name: start bot
              env:
                TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
              run: python test.py
```

The following error occurs at the "start bot" step in the workflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/test-repo/test-repo/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    SECRET = os.environ['SECRET']
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.11/x64/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 680, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

If i try to echo the SECRET in the workflow.yml i get ***, so it has has acces to the token, but when it imports to python it all breaks down.

I'm still quite new to git and GitHub, so please don't use advanced terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
            - name: start bot
              env:
                TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
```

In the GitHub Action you named the variable `secrets.SECRET` but in environment variables you named it `TOKEN`. Either change the name of the environment variable to `SECRET`:

```yaml
            - name: start bot
              env:
                SECRET: ${{ secrets.SECRET }}
```

or change your code:

```py
    SECRET = os.environ['TOKEN']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the workflow.yml, the variable was named "TOKEN", and in the test.py it was called "SECRET"